# Antimicro not detecting Controller input after install RetroPi

Tags: drivers, usb, gamepad

Antimicro was working fine until after I install RetroPi. It can detect there's a controller, but it can't detect the controller input. I've tried on both a USB flight stick and a xbox one s controller. The controllers work with other games and programs including JSTest but not antimicro.

```
squirel@TREEPC:~$ sudo antimicro 
"sni-qt/10081" WARN  12:24:00.455 void StatusNotifierItemFactory::connectToSnw() Invalid interface to SNW_SERVICE 
Virtual pointer found with id=4.
Changing mouse acceleration for device with id=4
Using XTest as the event generator.
```

---

```
squirel@TREEPC:~$ lsusb 
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0955:cf08 NVidia Corp. SHIELD Tablet
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 045e:02ea Microsoft Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 046d:c05a Logitech, Inc. M90/M100 Optical Mouse
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 058f:6362 Alcor Micro Corp. Flash Card Reader/Writer
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 045e:00db Microsoft Corp. Natural Ergonomic Keyboard 4000 V1.0
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```